# Cant generate signed apk,kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, apk, signed, android-lint

After upgrading my Android Studio to 3.2.1,
I encountered the following problem when creating Generate signed APK:

> Could not find lint-kotlin.jar
>   (com.android.tools.lint:lint-kotlin:26.2.1). Searched in the following
>   locations:
>       https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-kotlin/26.2.1/lint-kotlin-26.2.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

Add `jcenter()` in your list of repositories, e.g.

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter() 
}
```

Comment: Add google() first and then jcenter() to repositories

Comment: Add mavenCentral() before jcenter(), see: https://blog.autsoft.hu/a-confusing-dependency/amp/?__twitter_impression=true